# Why autofs can't mount my usbstick?

Tags: autofs

I've installed autofs package, and I know **/etc/auto.master** and **/etc/auto.misc** .
I set only one monitored path in **/etc/auto.master**:

```
/root/media /etc/auto.misc
```

Then I set **usb** sub-directory setting in **/etc/auto.misc**:

```
usb -fstype=auto,sync,nosuid,rw,gid=100,umask=000 :/dev/sdb1
```

I'm very sured that if I insert usbstick into system, it always in **/dev/sdb** and only one partition in FAT32 will be shown in **/dev/sdb1**.

And finally I restart autofs service certainly. But I just can't find anything in **/root/media** after I insert my usbstick.

There isn't **/root/media** pre-built, and I can found **/root/media** be built after I restart autofs service by executing **/etc/init.d/autofs restart**. Incidentally, I tried **/etc/init.d/autofs reload** already, and got a useless same result.

Anybody knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way, here's what I use. It's only good if you mount to the same mount point every time.

in /etc/udev/rules.d make a new file called automount.rules and put the following in it:

ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sdb*", RUN+="/bin/mount  /usb"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sdb*", RUN+="/bin/umount /usb"

in /etc/fstab put the following:

/dev/sdb1        /usb             auto        rw,user,noauto,noatime,umask=000

Then run this:  udevadm control --reload-rules

Now every time you insert any usb device it will be mounted on /usb. If this is not what you want to happen then you'll have to find something else.. But it works for me.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it isn't worked.
Maybe it is because that our system **shut the hot-plug function down in kernel**. So I will try script method to archive it.